# Can i safely delete MSSQL Server 2008 R2 after installing 2012?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I just upgraded my MS SQL Server 2008 R2 to 2012 on my local machine. Its all ok and there is no problems. All is working good (I mostly develop asp.net mvc applications and some desktop applications. All of them are pretty simple).
Can i safely delete 2008 server from my computer? Are there any things that i should care about?
Thank you.

Comment: Well, there are some problems when i try to remove sql 2008 after upgrading it to 2012 version. I cant safely remove sql 2008 components because they have dependence to 2012 version. Finally i completely removed sql 2008 and then i installed 2012 version.

Answer (score 3):

When I upgraded to SQL 2012, I first removed SQL 2008 completely in Programs and features and then installed SQL 2012.  This was fine and I had no problems.  Where ever practically possible I would recommend removing the old product first before installing the new.

I would think that removing SQL 2008 should be fine.  Worst case senario you may have to do a repair on SQL 2012 or re-install.